# Update shipping price in admin

Tags: edit-order

I have created a custom shipping module following this tutorial [adeptasoftware.co.uk/blog/magento-delivery-date-extension-part-1/](http://adeptasoftware.co.uk/blog/magento-delivery-date-extension-part-1/).

But when I edit the order, the shipping price is not passed to the new order.

Anybody has an idea where to look?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In Magento when you edit an order in admin, first you will need to add products and it will show shipping based on shipping address and you will need to select shipping option again than it will be add to grand total. Can you please explain your question in more detail what you want to achieve?

Comment: If I send POST_['shipping_amount'] and POST_['base_shipping_amount'] to an observer from the order edit form, and in the observer I set them as [shipping_amount] = string(5) 90.50 to object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address), why it is not saved? (I'm Mage::loging the Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address)